# Having issues with checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have two websites with three checkboxes on both of them. The thing i want to do is check a checkbox on the first website and it would show what i have checked on the other site. This works with only one checkbox but as soon as i check more than one box only one shows as checked on the other site. Here is some code:

`Website1.aspx` (Where they have to be checked)

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked)
{
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx?parm1=true");       
}
else if (CheckBox2.Checked)
{
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx?parm2=true");
}
else if (CheckBox3.Checked)
{
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx?parm3=true");
}
```

`Website2.aspx` (where they should show up as checked)

```
if (Request.QueryString["parm1"] != null)
{
    boxreg.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["parm1"]);
}
else if (Request.QueryString["parm2"] != null)
{
    boxhand.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["parm2"]);
}
else if (Request.QueryString["parm3"] != null)
{
    boxbeslut.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["parm3"]);
}
```

So the question is how would i go about if i want more than one checked and for it to show up on the other site. If i check only one for now it works but not for more than one.

Comment: @Ian Where would i put the parm=true part? I'm a beginner so i don't know that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, your code should be changed to something like this:

```
Website1.aspx

Response.Redirect("default.aspx?parm1=" + CheckBox1.Checked.ToString() + 
"&parm2=" + CheckBox2.Checked.ToString() + 
"&parm3=" + CheckBox3.Checked.ToString());
```

And also (note the three `ifs`):

```
Website2.aspx

if (Request.QueryString["parm1"] != null)
{
    boxreg.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["parm1"]);
}

if (Request.QueryString["parm2"] != null)
{
    boxhand.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["parm2"]);
}

if (Request.QueryString["parm3"] != null)
{
    boxbeslut.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["parm3"]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, great. :) glad that I can help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

First page

```
string params = "";

params+= CheckBox1.Checked ? "param1=true":"";
params+= CheckBox2.Checked ? "param2=true":"";
params+= CheckBox3.Checked ? "param3=true":"";

string url = "default.aspx"

url += params != "" ? "?" + params: "";
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Default.aspx

```
boxreg.Checked = Request.QueryString["parm1"] != null ? true: false;
boxhand.Checked = Request.QueryString["parm2"] != null ? true: false;
boxbeslut.Checked = Request.QueryString["parm3"] != null ? true: false;
```